# Linux NIC driver: what's the UDP packet from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255?

Tags: linux, udp, driver, nic

I am playing with rhel6 and rhel 7 NIC driver.

The interesting thing is, when I do "**`ifup eth0`**" (eth0 is the NIC associated with my driver), I found Linux will try to send two special UDP packets, with source address of `0.0.0.0` and destination address of `255.255.255.255`.

Can someone help me to understand what's the purpose of those UDP packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [DHCP Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_discovery) request. The interface is attempting to acquire an IP address from your DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what's the source addr and dest address for IPv6 DHCP Discovery?

Comment: Or let me ask the question in this way: how do I figure out a address is a SOURCE address for **IPv6** DHCP discovery message? is it **::/128** in any cases?